# How to create firestore document on user sign up

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I am trying to create a firestore document on user signup. the user is recorded after sign up but the document is not created. Everthing works well except the fact that the document is not created

```
import { db } from '../Firebase/Firebase';

    const handleSignup = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        createUser(email, password)
            .then(() => {
                db.collection('users').doc(currentUser.uid).set({
                    boards:[]
             })
                seterror(null)

            })
            .catch(error => {
                seterror(error)
            })
    }
```

Comment: Do you want this to happen in your runtime app? You might want to take a look to Firestore & Auth Cloud functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything looks fine try seperating boards first

```
import { db } from '../Firebase/Firebase';
const addBoards = {
        boards : [ ]
}
    const handleSignup = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        createUser(email, password)
            .then((user) => {
                db.collection('users').doc(user.user.uid).set(addBoards)
                seterror(null)

            })
            .catch(error => {
                seterror(error)
            })
    }
```